# Pass as parameter value from application.properties at class level Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have this part of code:

```
@Component
public class TestWriter implements ItemWriter<Test> {
    //  @Value("${test.param:3}")
    //  private int testParam;

    private final ForkJoinPool customThreadPool = new ForkJoinPool(3);
```

But in new ForkJoinPool(int parallelism) i want to pass as parameter my parameter from application.properties (testParam)

```
private final ForkJoinPool customThreadPool = new ForkJoinPool(testParam);
```

I tried to use Enviroment with my params but it doesnt work.

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;
...
dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
```

How can it be done if it possible and correct and what would be the correct way ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Contructor injection to be sure, the property is available when needed.

```
@Component
public class TestWriter implements ItemWriter<Test> {

     private final ForkJoinPool customThreadPool;

     @Autowired
     public TestWriter (@Value("${test.param:3}") int testParam) {
      this.customThreadPool = new ForkJoinPool(testParam);
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. 

Your solution works perfectly.

But finally i decided to create a @Bean to instance the ForkJoinPool with needed parameter, and then use it in my class.

Sorry for my bad English, and thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways in achieving this. One is through environmental variable, and other one is through property file.

1. Through Environment variable-

You'll need to set environment variable as `JDBC_URL=jdbc:postg...`.

and use it as below.

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;
...
dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("JDBC_URL"));
```

2. Through property file,

   @Value("${jdbc.url}")
   private String JDBC_URL;

In your application.properties, add

```
jdbc.url=jdbc:postg...
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I need to do it through property file. I already have a variable defined as  
`test.param = 3`
in my property file.

And i always use them like this


`@Value("${test.param:3}")`
`private int cantidadHilos;`

But i cant pass it as parameter to ForkJoinPool(testParam); I dont know in what moment spring initialize the variable and it gives me an error.

Comment: The variable will be initialised during bean creation. In your case, whenever TestWriter instance is created by Spring, the value will be injected.

Comment: This error it gives me:
`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null`
`at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.checkParallelism(ForkJoinPool.java:2546) ~[na:1.8.0_241]`

Comment: Can you check if application.properties is present at correct file hierarchy? @AlexDanilov

Comment: Yes, it is correct. I use application.properties parameters in all my project. the solution above works perfectly. Thanks for your responses and time.